# how to support inline comments when using eslint-prettier/prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb, eslintrc

i want to turn off the rule in prettier where it newlines an inline comment. my ESLint rule `no-inline-comments` is set to off or warn, so that is taken care of and works. turns out Prettier still wants to newline and inline comment:

[image]

i have a setup in my VSCode where ESLint is handling prettier for JS and the Prettier extension is handling all the other languages. im also using the `airbnb-base`. here are my relevant configs:

`.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-plusplus": 0,
    "no-inline-comments": "off",
    "no-undef": "warn",
    "no-use-before-define": "warn",
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      "warn",
      {
        "selector": "ForOfStatement",
        "message": "frowned upon using For...Of"
      }
    ]
    // "line-comment-position": ["warn", { "position": "above" }]
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "webextensions": true
  }
}
```

VSCode `settings.json`:

```
  // all auto-save configs
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  // turn off for native beautifyjs
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "prettier.disableLanguages": ["js"],
  "prettier.trailingComma": "es5"
}
```

i know you can do `// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier` above what you want ignored but i obviously wouldnt want to set that every time. you can see it commented out in my picture above.

> Generally, you get the best results when placing comments on their own lines, instead of at the end of lines. Prefer `// eslint-disable-next-line` over `// eslint-disable-line`.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#comments

im not sure if this is useful in this situation?:

> Note: While it is possible to pass options to Prettier via your ESLint configuration file, it is not recommended because editor extensions such as `prettier-atom` and `prettier-vscode` will read `.prettierrc`, but won't read settings from ESLint, which can lead to an inconsistent experience.

https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#options

ive talked to a few people and it might not even possible? though, it is a rule somewhere and that should be able to be overridden. if there is any other information i can provide i will.

Comment: I would love to have a solution for this, have you found any more info since your post?

Comment: im sorry to inform you that i have not found a solution to this. :(

Comment: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/807

This seems to be an open issue.

Comment: Any update on this? Using the `plugin-ruby` of prettier breaks inlined `rubocop:disable` rules

Comment: I too ran into the same problem and there is no solution yet :/

Answer (score 0):

---

### ESLint & Prettier both Support Inline Comments

---

##### The problem isn't the formatter or linter, its your "extends" field, among other issues.

Your using a slightly complex configuration. You added a plug-in that harmonizes ESLint & Prettier such that the can be used as if they were a single tool *(which is great)*. You also have extended your rule-set to adhere to a very nit-picky style-guide, not that a nit-picky style guide is bad, but the style-guide needs to format the code in a way that works for you. I'll get straight to the point, and inform you that...

###### **[Air-bnb's JavaScript Style-guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) doesn't allow inline-comments**

> ###### @see airbnb/javascript GitHub Repo → [Rules: 18.3 & 18.4](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#comments--singleline)

When you use a rule-set, you need to know what it does. The links above will take you to the Air-bnb JS style-guides official documentation. That documentation would have probably contained enough information for you to have answered this question yourself. Now you know, if you didn't before.

##### Get rid of the Air-bnb Style-guide

Obviously, air-bnb isn't a good choice for someone who wants to be able to write inline comments in there code. Personally, the only reason I think any style-guide as strict as air-bnb's guide, should be followed, is when working on a project that has many people contributing to it.

###### How to know when to switch style-guides?

If you find that your adding more than 3 or 4 rules to your ESLint's configuration file, that is a good indication that maybe the style-guide your using isn't for you. A style-guide should be a quick and easy way to configure your editor, if its not, and your project isn't a group project, why use one?

For this answer, I am going to suggest an "extends" configuration that supports inline-comments, and it is also ESLint's go to rule-set. *@See the snippet below.*

works for, which might be a custom style-guide. A good rounded base is the  following:

**        `"extends": ["eslint:recommended"]`**

###### The Prettier ESLint Plugin

You are also extending a configuration recommended by a plugin, to be honest, you need to know where your at with your rules, so what you want to do here, is follow the advice of the `ESLint-Plugin-Prettier` package's documentation. If you read the packages [**`README.md`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prettier) document it clearly states the following:

> ###### *Exactly what does plugin:prettier/recommended do? Well, this is what it expands to:*
>
> ```
>  {
>    "extends": ["prettier"],
>    "plugins": ["prettier"],
>    "rules": {
>      "prettier/prettier": "error",
>      "arrow-body-style": "off",
>      "prefer-arrow-callback": "off"
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> ---

What the quote above is saying, is that the snippet in the quote is the same as adding...

**`"extends": ["prettier", "plugin:prettier/recommended"]`**

###### Therefore, the configuration you should be using, is as follows:

```
  {
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "prettier"],
    "plugins": ["prettier"],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": "error",
      "arrow-body-style": "off",
      "prefer-arrow-callback": "off"
    }
  }
```

#### Now We Can Configure the Rules that affect Inline-Comments

###### *This is the `"rules"` field in a `.eslintrc.json` file. Don't add this configuration, just have a look.*

```
  "rules": {
    "no-inline-comments": "off", // Disable the rule that disables inline comments
    "max-len": [
      "error",
      {
        "code": 80, // Set to what ever you desire
        "tabWidth": 4, // Set to what ever you desire


        /* The two rules below are important, they configure ESLint such that 
           the value you assign to the `"code": 80` field above doesn't apply
           to inline comments. So your inline comment won't get chopped at, or      
           moved if it is too long. Set the following two fields to `true`. */

        "ignoreTrailingComments": true,
        "ignoreComments": true,
      }
    ]
  }
```

#### Final `eslintrc.json` configuration

***This is the configuration you should end up with:***

```
  {
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "prettier"],
    "plugins": ["prettier"],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": "error",
      "arrow-body-style": "off",
      "prefer-arrow-callback": "off",
      "no-inline-comments": "off",
      "max-len": [
        "error",
        {
          "code": 80,
          "tabWidth": 4,
          "ignoreTrailingComments": true,
          "ignoreComments": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

##### PRETTIER CONFIGURATION

In your prettier configuration, if you set a value for **`printWidth`**

```
  {
    "printWidth": 80, // <-- as shown here
  }
```

prettier will move your inline comments to another line, &/or break them up into pieces if they are longer (more characters than) the value assigned to `"printWidth"`, therefore, if you don't want your comments hacked at, or moved, set `printWidth` to a ridiculously high value, something like what is shown below:

```
  /** @file "./.prettierrc" */

  {
    "printWidth": 1000
  }
```

If you follow the directions above, you will not only lint/format your code with support for inline-comments, but you will be in control of your configuration from this time forward.

Comment: `A style-guide should be a quick and easy way to configure your editor, if it's not, and your project isn't a group project, why use one?`

For future you and your future team, for practice, or to adhere to a popular style guide are a few reasons to use one.